# Merge cells in Google Colaboratory

Tags: google-colaboratory

How can I merge two cells in Google's Colaboratory? In Jupyter Notebook you can do so using `ctrl` + `shift` + `m`.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

There's no such command in the menu.
But if you look at Tools > Keyboard shortcuts...

You will see 'Merge focused cell with next cell' which you can set your own shortcut key combination.

Comment: Can you highlight the steps with which one can set one's own shortcut key combination?

Comment: I use Chrome on my Macbook. Here's what I've tried.
- Tools > Keyboard shortcuts...
- Scroll down to find 'Merge focused cell with next cell'
- Select the empty INPUT box and press Shift + M
- "Shift + M" appear in the box as the new short cut
- Go to a cell, select it. Type Shift+M
- That cell merges with the next cell. So it's working.

Answer (score 14):

You can `CTRL+Click` the cells you want to combine. Then, right-click one of the highlighted cells, and then click "Merge selected cells"

Answer (score 3):

Go to 
Tools->Keyboard Shrotcuts-->
and then find "Merge selected cells" 
and also you can choose your key's combination too.

Answer (score 0):

select the respective cells in colab
and do:

Alt + shift + m
[To merge cells]

If you want own keybindings , visit the Tools > KeyBoard Shortcuts